# Is a lense with an aperture larger than f/8 useful with an EOS 80 D?

Tags: lens, aperture, focal-length

I have a EOS 80D and supposedly it has a max aperture of f/8. Does this mean that my camera can't take advantage of lenses with larger aperture? E.G. This one for example:

[Canon EF-S 24mm Camera Lens Bundle](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00P899OXM)

Comment: Whatever gave you the idea that the EOS 80D has a maximum aperture of f/8?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> So I have a EOS 80D and supposedly it has a max aperture of f/8.

That's incorrect. The aperture is in the lens, not the body. All Canon EF and EF-S lenses, including the one that came with your camera, have maximum apertures larger than f/8. For example, [here's an 80D kit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B071WSD5ZV) with a f/3.5-5.6 lens, meaning that the maximum aperture changes depending on focal length, but at the wide end it's an f/3.5 lens.

Your 80D will work with any EF or EF-S mount lens.

I think the source of the confusion is that [the 80D can autofocus with lenses that have a maximum aperture as slow as f/8](http://learn.usa.canon.com/resources/articles/2016/eos-80D/af_at_f8.shtml). AF systems work with the aperture wide open, and some lenses with relatively small maximum apertures, or combinations of lenses and teleconverter with small effective max apertures, prevent the AF system from working. For example, the 80D can autofocus with an EF 70-200mm f/4L and a 2x teleconverter, which increases the maximum aperture two stops to f/8.

Comment: Caleb, IMHO the lens you mention (1200mm) is only manual focus

Comment: @RomeoNinov Yes, that's a good point. The AF system can still indicate whether the selected point is in focus, of course. I don't know if an f/8 EF-mount lens that contains an autofocus motor exists.

Comment: Changed the example to something more realistic.

Comment: apologies for my ignorance, what is the wide end meant?

Comment: @nish1013  Caleb refered to a zoom lens with may aperture depending on the focal length. At the wide-angle end (18mm), that lens may open up to f/3.5, whereas at the tele end (55mm), it can open up only to f/5.6

Comment: Right... *wide end* means the wide angle part of the lens's zoom range.